# Listen to two exact (but independent) fields in a specific Firestore document with Flutter

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my chat app, when a user gets banned, I want to throw him out of the chat. Moreover, I have a pinned message (which has nothing to do with banning of users) which is on to of the chat view (via Stack). I now want to connect to Firestore to the specific document of the group and constantly observe, if the user is banned (does that cost a lot of bandwidth. Moreover I want to update the pinned status message. Both infos are in the same document in the fields (admin -> list of all banned users and pinnedMessage).

Note that I am using both Firestore and Realtime Database (Realtime Database exclusively for saving of chat messages and tokens for FCM), Firestore for the rest (group/user details etc.). I am also familiar with Streambuilder and Futurebuilder which I think are not appropriate here?

I also want to save resources...

Answer (score 0):

When you read or listen to a document in Firestore, you are always reading the entire contents of the document.  Unlike Realtime Database, you can cannot choose to listen to or read a specific field in a document from a mobile client.

If this means you would be reading too much data to accomplish a certain task, consider splitting the document up into multiple documents that contain only the data necessary for that task.

Comment: Do you see a problem that, in one screen, I am using Realtime Database for the chat messages and have a second 'always listening' connection to Firestore? I see no other chance how to kick a user (which is currently in a chat) out of this chat if he gets banned. Moreover, any idea how to implement a 'single document listener' for Firestore in Flutter?

Comment: It's kind of a vague question. Do whatever you need to do to get your requirements met.  If you have a different question about how to use Firebase products, please ask a new question to explain what you're unclear about.

Comment: To solve my above question and be as specific as possible: How do I constantly listen to one single Firestore document in Flutter?

Comment: Add a listener and never remove it.